# read files from hdfs using spark(Scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parquet

please tell me how to read files from hdfs. I'm just starting to work with Scala and Spark. I can read a separate file that lies in the folder:

```
val parqDF = spark.read.parquet("hdfs://nn1home:8020/user/stg/ads/year=2020/month=1/day=1/16_data.0.parq")
```

but I would like to read whole folder with all the parquets

and also, one more **important** question,
how can I **add columns to my dataframe with data from the path where there are my parquets**

*my thanks for any advice*

Comment: 1. spark.read.parquet(“inputPath”) - read files from folder
2.   spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles(“/path/to/dir”) -  to get an RDD of (key,value) pairs where key is the path and value is the content from each file.
3. DF.withColumn("name column", value)

Comment: @mvasyliv, thanks) please, would you show me an example, how can I see my dataframe with all fields later? "parquet +  fields from the path"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit
val inputPath = "<you path>"
val dataDF = spark.read.parquet(inputPath)
dataDF.printSchema()
//    root
//    |-- _c0: string (nullable = true)
//    |-- _c1: string (nullable = true)
//    |-- _c2: string (nullable = true)
//    |-- _c3: string (nullable = true)

val resDF = dataDF.withColumn("new_col", lit(inputPath))
resDF.printSchema
//    root
//    |-- _c0: string (nullable = true)
//    |-- _c1: string (nullable = true)
//    |-- _c2: string (nullable = true)
//    |-- _c3: string (nullable = true)
//    |-- new_col: string (nullable = false)

resDF.schema
//    res2: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(
//      StructField(_c0,StringType,true), 
//      StructField(_c1,StringType,true), 
//      StructField(_c2,StringType,true), 
//      StructField(_c3,StringType,true), 
//      StructField(new_col,StringType,false)
//    )

// resDF.show(false) - show data dataframe
```